# Find pdf of $f(x)$ such that $g(x)/f(x)$ is approximately a constant

Tags: probability, functions, fractions

My friend asked me a question that asks to find a pdf function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)/g(x)$ is approximately a constant, where $g(x)=\sqrt{e^{x^2}+e^x}$, and $f(x) \neq g(x)$. And the range of x is [-1,2] for both f(x) and g(x).

I have no idea what should I do this, can someone give me some hints (not need to be full solution).

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you mean the domain is $[-1,2]$? $g$ cannot take negative values

Comment: I meant the range of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write 
$$
  g(x) 
= \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n} + x^n}{n!}\right)^{1/2}
$$
and then just choose $f$ to be 
$$
        f(x) 
\propto \left( \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^{2n} + x^n}{n!}\right)^{1/2}
$$
for an $N$ that gives you the desired level of closeness.